# Alpaca API: How do I get 5 days worth of data for my portfolio?

Tags: api, trading

I’m using the `/v2/account/portfolio/history` endpoint with these parameters:
timeframe: 1D
period: 5D
date_end:2020-06-15

But i’m only getting 3 days of results and I know its because of the weekend. Is there another parameter that I can pass to ignore weekends? What can I do to get 5 days worth of data?
I'm using this Python library https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python

Comment: Maybe get 7 days?

Comment: @PaulT. thats what im thinking to. I just didnt want to have to calculate that. I would think the API would take that into consideration.

Comment: Would it not simply be 7D for period in the example?

Comment: @PaulT. I would have to check if the period is 5D and the `date_end` is not a Friday then I would change the period to 7D. I was just looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually stated on the GitHub itself, how to do this

```
api.get_portfolio_history(date_start=None, date_end=None, period=None, timeframe=None, extended_hours=None)
```

[(Screen Shot from GitHub)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9LxW.png)